# ng-select angular 5 change background color on hover for items in the option list

Tags: angular-ngselect

I am trying to change the background color of the item in the option list on :hover. I notice that there is a marked class that gets added to the div tag on hover.

I have this in my angular component that is using the ng-select component:

```
 ng-select {
    .ng-option {
      .marked {
        background-color: red;
      }
    }
  }
```

It is not working. What is the best way to handle changing the background color on hover for ng-select

Answer (score 4):

In your css/scss file:

```
.ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items .ng-option.ng-option-marked {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Don't forget to import the ng-select styles in your style.scss.

```
// Import ng-select component styles
@import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css";
```

If you want the dropdown button color to change on hover use:

```
.ng-select .ng-select-container:hover{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ng-dropdown-panel {
  .ng-option {
    &.ng-option-marked {
      background-color: red !important;

      &:hover {
        background-color: blue !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You might also want to style the chosen option.

```
.ng-dropdown-panel {
  .ng-option {
    &.ng-option-selected {
      background-color: green !important;

      &:hover {
        background-color: purple !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I used scss I converted the css from ng-select to scss and then imported the scss files and made changes wherever I had to. Hope this helps.